# Problem With Input Form, Buttons, and FlexBox

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to evenly space 2 buttons and an input form in a flexbox. I had only 1 button and the input form and used space between and it worked fine. Then I added another button that used space evenly and the input form was bigger. I changed from a set width to a flex-grow, which made the input form much smaller. I am not sure if the input form has some default parameters that are causing this issue. I tried adjusting the size of the placeholder text thinking flex-grow might not factor that in and it did not work.

```css
* {
  border: black 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27);
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

#gridContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  display: grid;
  border: solid rgb(218, 27, 27) 8px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FAE481;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#clear,
.number,
#generator {
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid black;
  color: #FAE481;
  background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27);
}

input::placeholder {
  background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27);
  color: #FAE481;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    <button id="generator">Random Grid</button>
    <form id="inputForm">
      <input type="number" class="number" min=1 max=64 placeholder="Enter a # 1-64">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="gridContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I would recommend putting the buttons inside the form element, and then setting the form element to `display: flex`. That worked nicely for me. I haven't posted it as an answer because it's not quite clear how you'd like these elements laid out (with gaps between, all same size, etc?).

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear exactly what your intentions are, but I suspect the issue is with the input box being smooshed while the buttons have extra room. This is because you applied flex styles to the two `button`s and then the `input` instead of the `form`. Flexbox is applied only to the direct children of the container.

For what I'm guessing your intentions are, include `#inputForm` in the `#clear, .number, #generator { }` rule and also add `width: 100%;`

You'll likely want to cancel out the double border on the `input`, so add `.number {border: 0;}`

```css
* {
    border: black 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27);
    /* min-height: 100vh; */
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

#gridContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    display: grid;
    border: solid rgb(218, 27, 27) 8px;
}

.header {
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FAE481;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
      input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
      }

#clear, .number, #generator, #inputForm {
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 4px solid black;
    color: #FAE481;
    background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27);
}

.number {
    border: 0;
}

input::placeholder {
    /* background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27); */
    color: #FAE481;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    <button id="generator">Random Grid</button>
    <form id="inputForm">
       <input type="number" class="number" min=1 max=64 placeholder="Enter a # 1-64">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="gridContainer"></div>
```

I read the [comment from ralph.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76510830/problem-with-input-form-buttons-and-flexbox#comment134903499_76510830) and thought hmmm, let me try that. I think this does make a cleaner approach and you can remove `<div class="buttons">`. I think you'll prefer `width: 100%;` instead of `flex-grow: 1;`

```css
* {
    border: black 1px solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27);
    /* min-height: 100vh; */
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

#gridContainer {
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    display: grid;
    border: solid rgb(218, 27, 27) 8px;
}

.header {
    /* display: flex; */
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FAE481;
}

#inputForm {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
      input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
      }

#clear, .number, #generator {
    /* flex-grow: 1; */
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 4px solid black;
    color: #FAE481;
    background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27);
}

input::placeholder {
    /* background-color: rgb(218, 27, 27); */
    color: #FAE481;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>
  <form id="inputForm">
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    <button id="generator">Random Grid</button>
    <input class="number" type="number" min=1 max=64 placeholder="Enter a # 1-64">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="gridContainer"></div>
```